# How to modify a perl script to read excel instead of Html files

Tags: excel, perl

My first question is:

> Is this possible to do this, since now I have a perl script which reads Html file and extract data to display on another html file.

If the answer for the question above is Yes, my second question would be:

> How to do this?

Sorry to ask frankly as this, but since I'm so new for perl, and I have to take this task, so I'm here for some useful advice or suggestion to guide me through this task. Appreciate your help in advance.

Here's a part of the code, since the whole chunk is quite long:

```
$date=localtime();
($TWDAY, $TMTH, $TD1D, $TSE, $TYY) = split(/\s+/, $date);
$TSE =~ s/\://g;
$STAMP=_."$TD1D$TMTH$TYY";

@ServerInfo=();

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------   -------------------------------
# Read Directory
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
$myDir=getcwd;

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# INITIALIZE HTML FORMAT
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
&HTML_FORMAT;
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# REPORT 
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
if (! -d "$myDir/report") { mkdir("$myDir/report");};

$REPORTFILE="$myDir/report/checkpack".".htm";

open OUT,">$REPORTFILE" or die "\nCannot open out file $REPORTFILE\n\n";
print OUT "$Tag_Header";
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  

sub numSort {
if ($b < $a) { return -1; }
elsif ($a == $b) { return 0;}
elsif ($b > $a) { return 1; }
}

@ArrayDir = sort numSort @DirArray;

#while (<@ArrayDir>) {

@OutputDir=grep { -f and -T } glob "$myDir/*.htm $myDir/*.html";
#}

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@ReadLine3=();

$xyxycnt=0;


foreach $InputFile (@OutputDir) { #---- MAIN

$filename=(split /\//, $InputFile) [-1]; print "-"x80 ; print     "\nFilename\t:$filename\n";

open IN, "<$InputFile" or die "Cannot open Input file $InputFile\n";
@MyData=();
$DataCnt=0;
@MyLine=();
$MyLineCnt=0;

while (<IN>) {
$LINE=$_;
chomp($LINE);

$LINE=~s/\<br\>/XYXY/ig;
$LINE=~s/\<\/td\>/ \nXYZXYZ\n/ig;

$LINE=~s/\<dirname\>/xxxdirnameyyy/ig;

$LINE=linetrim3($LINE);
$LINE=linetrim($LINE);

$LINE=~s/XYXY/\<br\>/ig;

$LINE=~s/xxxdirnameyyy/&lt dirname &gt/ig;

$LINE=~s/^\s+//ig;
print OUT2 "$LINE\n";

if (defined($LINE)) { $MyData[$DataCnt]="$LINE"; $DataCnt++ ; }

}

close IN;

foreach $ReadFile (@MyData) {  #--- Mydata
$MyLineCnt++;
$MyLine[$MyLineCnt]="";

#### FILENAME
$ServerInfo[0]="$filename";

#### IP ADDRESS
if ($ReadFile =~ /Host\/Device Name\:/)     { 
    #print "$ReadFile\n"
    ($Hostname)=(split /\:|\s+/, $ReadFile)[3]; print "$Hostname\n";
    &myServerInfo("$Hostname","1");

}
if ($ReadFile =~ /IP Address\(es\)/)        {@ListIP=(); $SwIP=1; $CntIP=0 ; };


#### OPERATING SYSTEM & VERSION
if ($ReadFile =~ /Operating System\:/)      { 
    $SwIP=0;
    $OS=    (split /\:|\s+/, $ReadFile)[3]; &myServerInfo("$OS","3") ; print "$OS\n";
    $OSVer= (split /\:|\s+/, $ReadFile)[-2]; &myServerInfo("$OSVer","4") ; print "$OSVer\n";

};

#### GET IP VALUE
if ($SwIP==1) {
    $ReadFile=(split /\:/,$ReadFile) [2];
    $ReadFile=~s/[a-z|A-Z]|\(|\)|\// /ig; print "$ReadFile\n";
    if ($CntIP==0) {
        #$ListIP[$CntIP]=(split /\s+/,$ReadFile) [1];
        @ListIP="$ReadFile";

    } elsif ($CntIP==1) { print "\n\t\t  $ReadFile\n" ; $ListIP[$CntIP]="\n$ReadFile"; 
    } else  { print "\t\t  $ReadFile\n" ; $ListIP[$CntIP]="\n$ReadFile"; };
     $CntIP++;
}
```

Comment: Answer is _Yes_. Show your code.

Comment: @serenesat uploaded alr, I will post more if needed

Comment: Your code is **very** old. Probably you don't really have a clue what it is doing. You cannot just switch a few lines and get parsing of XLS instead of HTML. I suggest you start by figuring out what the output should be like and then write a new program to do that from your input XLS file. There are good modules to parse XLS on CPAN, like https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::ParseExcel.

Comment: @simbabque the output should be also be in excel form

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid if you don't understand what is going on in this program and you also don't understand how to approach a task like this at all, Stack Overflow might not be the right place to get help.

---

Let me try to show you the approach I would take with this. I'm assuming there is more code.

- First, write down a list of everything you know:

  - What is the input format of the *existing file*
  - Where does the *existing file* come from now
  - What is the output format of the *existing file*
  - Where does the *generated output file* go afterwards
  - What does the *new file* look like
  - Where does the *new file* come from
- Use [perltidy](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Perl-Tidy/bin/perltidy) to indent the inherited code so you can read it better. The default options should be enough.
- Read the code, take notes about what pieces do what, add comments
- Write a [unit test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) for the desired output format. You can use [Test::More](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::More). Another useful testing module here is [Test::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::File).
- [Refactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) the part that generated the output format to work with a certain data structure. Use your tests to make sure you don't break it.
- Write code to parse the new file into the data structure from the point above. Now you can plug that in and get the expected output.
- Refactor the part that takes the old input file from the existing file location to be a function, so you can later switch it for the new one.
- Write code to get the new file from the new file location.
- Document what you did so the next guy is not in the same situation. Remember that could be you in half a year.

Also add `use strict` and `use warnings` while you refactor to catch errors more easily. If stuff breaks because of that, make it work before you continue. Those pragmas tell you what's wrong. The most common one you will encounter is *Global symbol "$foo" requires explicit package name*. That means you need to put `my` in front of the first assignment, or declare the variable before.

If you have **specific** questions, ask them as a new question with a short example. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure you will get help on those.

Good luck!

---

After seing [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776475/how-to-modify-a-perl-script-to-read-excel-instead-of-html-files?noredirect=1#comment49644620_30776475) I am thinking you want a different input and a different output. In that case, disregard this, throw away the old code and start from scratch. If you don't know enough Perl, get a book like Curtis Poe's *Beginning Perl* if you already know programming. If not, check out *Learning Perl* by Randal L. Schwartz.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it shows to me how big is this world of Perl and those steps I need to take on before moving forward. But the problem is my work is quite urgent, so I won't have enough time to read a book first, is there any basic script I could use to extract data from an excel file, and I could learn from it to get the basics of Perl.

Comment: No. There is no such thing as "some script that does x" in any language. There're tools to achieve things, but you need to glue them together. If you need to build a conversion from one format to another, you might consider doing it in a language you are comfortable with, especially if it's urgent. Perl is not a collection scripts (like *Matt's Script Archive*) any more. It's a programming language with an ecosystem that is used in huge projects, just like PHP, Python, Ruby or others. That said, my explanation of how to approach this task is not Perl-specific. It's about *software-development*

Comment: In general I need to extract data from one folder of excel files, I would love to solve the problem with VBA which I'm more familiar with, otherwise would you recommend any other ways to solve this problem, as to software-development you mentioned in the comment.

Comment: My explanations here were for refactoring the old thing you have. Since that is not the case, you need a different approach. Where's the problem in doing that in VBA? Read files, extract data per file, do something to the data, write output file.

Comment: The problem is the script is going to read more than one files at one folder, is VBA able to do it? And I'm worried VBA would be not efficient and powerful enough to process this.